# Gaps in between css background fill repeats

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

So this is pretty hard to fit it all into a js fiddle so please see [the website](http://dunnrite.co.uk/frame2).

Basically I have a jquery thing of

```
$("#patterns #pattern11").click (function() {
    $('#text').removeClass();
    $('#text').addClass('background11');
});
```

which means that when a pattern under "frame background" is clicked it changes the background on the frame. So this works nicely except for that fact that these lines appear through the background.

Here is the css class being added

```
    .background11 {
    color: white;  /* Fallback: assume this color ON TOP of image */
   background: url("Images/pattern11.jpg");
   background-size:100px;
}
```

I have a few ideas which i've tried. Either the z-index needs changing, there is a padding/margin issue, a background property in need of changing or something else.

Thanks

Comment: Hi try this $('#text').removeClass("class name to be removed");

Comment: Try fixing the images, it looks like the images each have a 1px line at either top/bottom which is either white/transparent. Doesn't look like a problem with CSS/Javascript/jQuery

Comment: Actually, try removing the `background-size:100px;` attribute from css. Is there a reason you added this?

Comment: You need to give width and height of the image(pattern11.jpg) in css

Comment: @Robin that isn't it. My remove class removes any previous class as I won't know the name of the class to remove.

Comment: @Nunners the background size just adjusts how big the background looks. I tried removing it but it doesn't get rid of the problem.

Comment: and @Nunners it can't be that. Try under frame type changing from white to black. You will notice the line colour changes too so this is my reasoning for a gap.

Comment: @dunn_rite As I said, it could also be a transparent line. That would account for the effect you are seeing. There is nothing wrong with the CSS / Javascript from my tests so it must be the Images themselves

Comment: you are right about the images themselves. Needed a more specific answer to solve but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having problems because you are resizing the original images in your patterns and not keeping exactly the same aspect ratios.  So you are ending up with a stray pixel or so on the edges of your image patterns.

For example, take pattern "patt2":

```
<pattern id="patt2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="400" height="500">
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="Images/pattern2.jpg"
           x="0" y="0" width="700" height="1000"></image>
</pattern>
```

The image "pattern2.jpg" is 542x774, but you are scaling it to 700x1000, which is not exactly the same ratio.  It is off by a fraction.

If you redefine the pattern like so:

```
<pattern id="patt2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="400" height="500">
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="Images/pattern2.jpg"
           x="0" y="0" width="542" height="774"></image>
</pattern>
```

The lines disappear.

Alternatively you could tell the browser to use a scaling mode which will hide the gaps.  You do that with the attribute "preserveAspectRatio".

The value "none" will work.  It should guarantee that the image fills the dimensions you ask for without leaving stray pixels:

```
<pattern id="patt2" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="400" height="500">
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="Images/pattern2.jpg"
           x="0" y="0" width="700" height="1000" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
</pattern>
```

Comment: Ah perfect thank you! So in future make sure images are scaled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There might be few reasons this happens to you:

1. Your background size is set to `background-size:100px;` try removing it, instead of that add width and height.
2. There might be problem with your image, try opening it with PS and zoom and check if borders doesn't contain any mistakes (white spaces). Sometimes if you miss 1px borders on your image you might not be able to see it in image, but HTML might interpretate it differently.